# Flutter - there is an issue with LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter

```
The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field '_isReverse@39039112' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      CountDownController._isReverse (package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart)
#1      CountDownController.start (package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart:307:9)
#2      _MediterranesnDietViewState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:halesowen_gym_project/Screens/sidebar_menu/fitness_app/ui_view/mediterranean_diet_view.dart:463:68)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:267:7)
#8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
#10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#11     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
#12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
#20     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
#21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#e30e3
```

I have the above error. I have created a CircularCountDownTimer and I have a controller on my stageful widget. So when I try to start the countdown with _controller.start(); I'm getting the above error.

Notice: I've tried the full example from the documentation and it works so I'm pretty sure that is not a problem of the package. Also I'm not using any variable as late to define it.

Any suggestion ?

**UPDATE: ----------------------------------**

Below I'll paste the code, I tried to declare it only on initState but I cannot get access to the variable and the code that I'm posting now isn't working, getting the same error. There is only one place where I'm calling the controller so you can search and find it.

```
  final AnimationController? animationController;
  final Animation<double>? animation;

  const MediterranesnDietView(
      {Key? key, this.animationController, this.animation})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MediterranesnDietViewState createState() => _MediterranesnDietViewState();
}

class _MediterranesnDietViewState extends State<MediterranesnDietView> {
// final int _duration = 10;

CountDownController _controller = CountDownController();
 @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = CountDownController();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(.........

Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9)),
                                    color: FitnessAppTheme.nearlyWhite,
                                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: FitnessAppTheme.nearlyDarkBlue
                                              .withOpacity(0.4),
                                          offset: const Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                                          blurRadius: 8.0),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                    child: TextButton(
                                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () => _controller.start(),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'START',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: FitnessAppTheme.fontName,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          letterSpacing: -0.2,
                                          color: FitnessAppTheme.darkText,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: This error is thrown when build runs and therin is a late variable that has been initialized within the build method or has not been initialized at all. Try moving your _controller.start() into either the initState() or the didChangeDependancies() methods. The latter if you have use for Buildcontext. For better understanding of your problem, paste the code

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I know that but I can't get why the variable isn't ready. I've posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution!
I think initialization takes some time.

Wrap your method with Future.delayed like:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
      _controller.start();
});
```